# WooCommerce: Create custom email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I am trying to create a review reminder email using the **Customer invoice / Order details** email. We don't use this email so I thought it would be good to change the code to make it a review reminder email and then we can trigger it manually.

I have changed a bit of code, so it now looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Customer completed order email
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-completed-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version 3.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
  exit;
}

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>


<?php /* translators: %s: Customer first name */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_billing_first_name() ) ); ?></p>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__("the more you share, the more you help other customers. We would love to know your thoughts on your most recent purchase and we'd appreciate it if you could take a moment to write a quick review.", 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( wp_specialchars_decode( get_option( 'blogname' ), ENT_QUOTES ) ) ); ?></p>
<?php

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_details() Shows the order details table.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_order_data() Generates structured data.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::output_structured_data() Outputs structured data.
 * @since 2.5.0
 */

$text_align = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';


  if ( $sent_to_admin ) {
    $before = '<a class="link" href="' . esc_url( $order->get_edit_order_url() ) . '">';
    $after  = '</a>';
  } else {
    $before = '';
    $after  = '';
  }
  /* translators: %s: Order ID. */
  ?>
</h2>

<div style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
  <table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
<tbody>
      <?php
      echo wc_get_email_order_items( $order, array( // WPCS: XSS ok.
        'show_sku'      => $sent_to_admin,
        'show_image'    => true,
        'image_size'    => array( 100, 100 ),
        'plain_text'    => $plain_text,
        'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin,
      ) );
      ?>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


<p>
<?php esc_html_e( 'Thanks for shopping with us.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
</p>
<?php

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_footer() Output the email footer
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

I need to add 3 things though:

1. A *static image*, below the header, pointing to an image in the media library.
2. A *URL link* to the particular product purchased.
3. This query gives me the product name (and image), quantity and price. I want to get rid of quantity and price and just have the name and image.

I don't want to mess with the main email template code though, so I want to be able to do these things all within this one php file.

Can someone please advise on any of these three items? Thanks!

Comment: Hello try this article once https://www.ibenic.com/create-custom-woocommerce-email/

Comment: Have you got solution for this ?

Comment: Yes I did. I hacked one of the other templates I don't use.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the ***email-order-items.php*** form ***plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/*** to your ***wp-content/themefolder/woocommerce/emails/email-order-item.php*** by doing this you can edit the layout of your email without touching the core functions of woocommerce. The details are already there including the image and the title.

Comment: But if i edit this file - will it not change it for all the emails?

Comment: @Michelle Yes it will